# A beginners issue for c++

Tags: c++, string, cin

This program is designed to take an integer and a name of less than 15 characters, and store them in arrays.

When a 0 is entered, the program displays the contents of the arrays, then terminates. Obviously, something here is amiss...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

bool getInput(int*, char(*)[15]);
void giveOutput(int*, char(*)[15]);

int main(void)
{
    bool repeat = true;
    int number[100] = {0};
    char name[100][15];
    do
    {
        repeat = getInput(number, name);
    } while(repeat);
    giveOutput(number, name);
    return 0;
}

void giveOutput(int* number, char(*name)[15])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(number[i] != 0)
    {
        cout << endl << i << setw(6) << name[i];
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    return;
}

bool getInput(int* number, char(*name)[15])
{
    int temp;
    int i = 0;
    for(; number[i] != 0; i++);
    cin >> temp;
    if(temp == 0)
        return false;
    number[i] = temp;
    cin.getline(name[i], 15, '\n');
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(512, '\n');
    return true;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this problem. The program does not perform as expected; it does not output the text entered following the number.
Also, this website keeps spamming me, telling me that my question is mostly code. So I'm writting a bunch of jibberish to try and appease the damn machine. Hopefully this is enough and I can finally post my question.

Comment: Welcome the Stack Overflow. You should know that normally users expect people to put some effort on their questions. If you state what is exactly the problem and what you tried you will get better chances. In your case, it seems that you start by using the debugger. Try using the debugger and come back with more details if you still have trouble.

Comment: Just to help with question formatting. Try to use smaller snippits of your code, rather than the entire thing. Describing what the purpose of the program is and how it isn't working in the question will help tremendously for people trying to help you.

Comment: For starters, your output function will only output your index (`i`) and the name.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

bool getInput(int*, char(*)[15]);
void giveOutput(int*, char(*)[15]);

int main(void)
{
  bool repeat = true;
  int number[100] = {0};
  char name[100][15];
  do
  {
    repeat = getInput(number, name);
  } while(repeat);
  giveOutput(number, name);
  return 0;
}

void giveOutput(int* number, char(*name)[15])
{
  int i = 0;
  while(number[i] != 0)
  {
    cout << endl << number[i] << setw(6) << name[i];
    i++;
  }
  cout << endl << endl;
  return;
}

bool getInput(int* number, char(*name)[15])
{
  int temp;
  int i = 0;
  for(; number[i] != 0; i++);
  cin >> temp;
  if(temp == 0) return false;
  number[i] = temp;
  cin.getline(name[i], 15, '\n');
  cin.clear();
  //cin.ignore(512, '\n');
  return true;
}
```

You shouldn't emulate garbage collector after cin.clear() call.

P.S. Only two changes: 1) output number[i] instead of i in giveOutput; 2) take out cin.ignore().

Comment: The `cin.clear` call is not really useful unless you are actually checking for error conditions.